# Compilation issues with Qt/OpenGL/GPU application on MacOS 10.6

Tags: qt, opengl, makefile, opencl, osx-snow-leopard

I try to compile on MacOS 10.6.8 an application which already works on Linux/Debian 7.0. This code uses Qt framework with GPU/OPenCL and OpenGL libraries.

But I get problems on compilation with this file header (GLWidget.hpp) (I put here the original Linux version) :

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H                                                    

#include <QGLWidget>                                              
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <QTimer>                                                     
#include "NBody.hpp"                                                  
#include "Timer.h"

 class GLWidget : public QGLWidget                                    
 {
     Q_OBJECT 

 public:      
     GLWidget(QWidget *parent = NULL);      



     ~GLWidget();

...
```

With this version, I have on MacOS compilation :

```
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -c -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/opt/local/include -I/Developer/GPU\ Computing/OpenCL/common/inc -I/opt/local/share/qt4/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks -I//Developer/GPU\ Computing/shared/inc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Headers -o GLWidget.o GLWidget.cpp
GLWidget.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void GLWidget::initializeGL()’:
GLWidget.cpp:82: error: ‘GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR’ was not declared in this scope
GLWidget.cpp:82: error: ‘glClampColor’ was not declared in this scope
GLWidget.cpp: In function ‘bool loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, GLubyte**)’:
GLWidget.cpp:297: error: ‘png_infopp_NULL’ was not declared in this scope
GLWidget.cpp:313: error: ‘png_infopp_NULL’ was not declared in this scope
GLWidget.cpp:347: error: ‘png_voidp_NULL’ was not declared in this scope
GLWidget.cpp:349: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct png_info_def’
/opt/local/include/png.h:739: error: forward declaration of ‘struct png_info_def’
GLWidget.cpp:350: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct png_info_def’
/opt/local/include/png.h:739: error: forward declaration of ‘struct png_info_def’
GLWidget.cpp:351: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct png_info_def’
/opt/local/include/png.h:739: error: forward declaration of ‘struct png_info_def’
GLWidget.cpp:359: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct png_info_def’
/opt/local/include/png.h:739: error: forward declaration of ‘struct png_info_def’
GLWidget.cpp:378: error: ‘png_infopp_NULL’ was not declared in this scope
GLWidget.cpp: In member function ‘void GLWidget::draw()’:
GLWidget.cpp:483: error: ‘GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE_NV’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [GLWidget.o] Error 1
```

Actually, `glClampColor` function is not declared in scope. So I have searched where this function is dclared and I found it in this file :

```
/Developer/GPU Computing/C/common/inc/GL/glew.h
```

Then, I have added it in the PATH and included it in GLWidget.hpp :

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <QTimer>
#include "NBody.hpp"
#include "Timer.h"

 class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:

     GLWidget(QWidget *parent = NULL);

     ~GLWidget();
```

But now, I get the following errors :

```
/opt/local/bin/uic DiskGal_IC.ui -o ui_DiskGal_IC.h
/opt/local/bin/uic YourGalaxy.ui -o ui_YourGalaxy.h
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -c -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/opt/local/include -I/Developer/GPU\ Computing/OpenCL/common/inc -I/opt/local/share/qt4/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks -I//Developer/GPU\ Computing/shared/inc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Headers -o DiskGal_IC.o DiskGal_IC.cpp
In file included from GLWidget.hpp:5,
                 from YourGalaxy.h:30,
                 from DiskGal_IC.h:25,
                 from DiskGal_IC.cpp:1:
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:66:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:69:2: error: #error glext.h included before glew.h
In file included from GLWidget.hpp:5,
                 from YourGalaxy.h:30,
                 from DiskGal_IC.h:25,
                 from DiskGal_IC.cpp:1:
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:5855: error: ‘GLint64EXT’ has not been declared
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:5856: error: ‘GLuint64EXT’ has not been declared
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:9020: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC’ does not name a type
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:9021: error: ‘PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC’ does not name a type
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:9022: error: ‘PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC’ does not name a type
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:9023: error: ‘PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC’ does not name a type
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:9025: error: ‘PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC’ does not name a type
//Developer/GPU Computing/shared/inc/GL/glew.h:9026: error: ‘PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC’ does not name a type
...
```

I don't know what to do, my Makefile has been generated by qmake with, in my .pro, `QT += opengl`. After, I have modified it to include others headers/libraries like OpenCL. Here's top part of this Makefile :

```
CC            = /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CXX           = /usr/bin/g++-4.2
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
GPU        = /Developer/GPU\ Computing
INC_GSL       = /opt/local/include
INCPATH       = -I$(INC_GSL) -I$(GPU)/OpenCL/common/inc -I/opt/local/share/qt4/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks -I/$(GPU)/shared/inc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Headers
LINK          = /usr/bin/g++-4.2
LFLAGS        = -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks -F/opt/local/lib -F/System/Library/Frameworks -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks -F/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -framework QtOpenGL -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -framework OpenCL -lgsl -lgslcblas -lfftw3 -L$(GPU)/shared/lib/darwin -lGLEW
```

Comment: try changing the headers order, glew requires to be included before gl.h e glext.h. gl.h is probably included by qglwidget and so it becomes included before glew in your case. that explains the first 2 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use GLEW on OS X. It will not accomplish much due to the way OS X implements OpenGL - the extensions it offers are all available at compile-time, there is no need to do run-time extension loading.

If an extension is not available when you compile your software on OS X, you are out of luck because the platform is designed to provide a homogeneous feature-set across all Apple-supported hardware (Hackintosh is a different story) on any given version, (e.g. any OS X 10.8 install will offer OpenGL 3.2 and the same set of extensions). This is why you wind up targeting OS X release numbers when you need certain OpenGL features.

Having said that, if you `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>` and acquire an OpenGL 3.2 core context on OS X (10.7+), `glClampColor (...)` will be defined and useable. Also, if you have an OpenGL 3.2 core context then `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE_NV` is unnecessary, it is core in OpenGL 3.2 and the non-vendor-specific token was renamed from `GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE` to simply **`GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`**.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to use OpenGL headers and libraries provided by the GPU Computing SDK (from Nvidia) and the only header wich contains glClampColor prototype is /Developer/GPU Computing/C/common/inc/GL/glew.h

Comment: Then you are out of luck, and cannot do this on OS X, sadly. Why do not you want to use the OpenGL libraries and headers that ship with your platform? That is the only portable way to do this kind of thing.